# prime seive algorithm giving a runtime error

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm but it giving a runtime error.
didn't get any output though. after providing the input,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//Sieve Approach - Generate an array containing prime Numbers
void prime_sieve(int *p) {

//first mark all odd number's prime
for (int i = 3; i <= 10000; i += 2) {
    p[i] = 1;
}

// Sieve
for (long long int i = 3; i <= 10000; i += 2) {
    //if the current number is not marked (it is prime)
    if (p[i] == 1) {
        //mark all the multiples of i as not prime
        for (long long int j = i * i; j <= 10000; j = j + i ) {
            p[j] = 0;
        }
    }

}
//special case
p[2] = 1;
p[1] = p[0] = 0;

}



int main() {

int n;
cin >> n;

int p[10000] = {0};
prime_sieve(p);

//lets print primes upto range n
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (p[i] == 1) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

compiler didn't throwing any error also it is not providing the output also
program freezes for some seconds and then terminates

Comment: `(int i = 3; i <= 10000; i += 2) ` is an off by 1 error since your array is `int p[10000] = {0};` and has valid indices of 0 .. 9999. You appear to repeat this bug several times.

Comment: @dr this will actually stop at `i = 9999` because of the 2 increment, but yeah that `<=` is still dangerous style. The `j` loop will bite them though when `i=5` for example, in that case `j` *will* eventually equal 10,000.

Comment: The "freezing for several seconds" is just the program churning through data. Computers are fast, but iterating through that many integers will take time.

Comment: After you fix your off-by-one loop errors, you can also improve efficiency by only having `i` loop from 3 to `sqrt(n)` (instead of up to `n`) in your sieve function.

Comment: *compiler didn't throwing any error* -- Don't know what you mean exactly, but if you mean that there are no compiler errors, all that means is that your program has no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether your program is logically correct or not.

Comment: If you use a `vector` instead of a variable-length array, then your iteration conditional changes to `i < v.size()`, and some compilers may warn if you do `i <= v.size()` instead. I don't think any compiler could warn about this issue when iterating up a pointer.

Comment: With a vector at() would throw an exception if you go out of bounds.

Comment: Note: `p[.]` should be initialised with 1 value. And you are not using  `n` in the Sieve function

Comment: Why use long long int? Use int only. No need long long int .long long int compare with int may be give error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are going out of bound.

There is also some confusion about the meaning of `p[]`.

In addition, you are not using the value of `n` in the function, which leads to unnecessary calculations.

Here is a tested programme (up to n = 10000):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


//Sieve Approach - Generate an array containing prime Numbers less than n
void prime_sieve(std::vector<int> &p, long long int n) {

    //first mark all odd number's prime
    for (long long int i = 4; i <= n; i += 2) {
        p[i] = 0;
    }

    // Sieve
    for (long long int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2) {
        //if the current number is not marked (it is prime)
        if (p[i] == 1) {
            //mark all the multiples of i as not prime
            for (long long int j = i * i; j <= n; j = j + i ) {
                p[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //special cases
    p[1] = p[0] = 0;
}



int main() {

    long long int n;
    std::cout << "Enter n: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> p (n+1, 1);

    prime_sieve(p, n);

    //lets print primes upto range n
    for (long long int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (p[i] == 1) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```